Postgresql select nearest max value row within 30 seconds timestamp
I need to extract data from a postgres table, where I want to look at nearby records within a 30 seconds of timesstamp with two columns match and fetch the value which is having max value.
 id    |    datetime         | col_1 | col_2|dist|  dir
-------+---------------------+-------+------+----+------
 103   | 2023-10-06 20:12:19 |   135 |   13 | 57 | EAST
 213   | 2023-10-06 20:32:34 |   135 |   13 | 54 | NORTH
 103   | 2023-10-06 20:00:19 |   135 |   13 | 70 | EAST
 103   | 2023-10-06 20:42:34 |   135 |   13 | 54 | NORTH
 213   | 2023-10-06 20:12:19 |   135 |   13 | 57 | NORTH
 222   | 2023-10-06 18:42:34 |   135 |   13 | 45 | EAST
 222   | 2023-10-06 20:42:34 |   135 |   13 | 54 | EAST

First, 'id' and 'dir' column should be same then need to check the 'datetime' values with in 30 mins range and get all column values where 'dist' column value is max.
Output -
  id   |    datetime         | col_1 | col_2|dist|  dir
-------+---------------------+-------+------+----+------
 103   | 2023-10-06 20:00:19 |   135 |   13 | 70 | EAST
 213   | 2023-10-06 20:12:19 |   135 |   13 | 57 | NORTH
 103   | 2023-10-06 20:42:34 |   135 |   13 | 54 | NORTH
 222   | 2023-10-06 18:42:34 |   135 |   13 | 45 | EAST
 222   | 2023-10-06 20:42:34 |   135 |   13 | 54 | EAST

I am trying below query but didn't work-
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, datetime, col_1, col_2, dist, dir
              FROM table_1)
SELECT table_1.*
FROM table_1
JOIN cte ON table_1.id = cte.id AND table_1.dir = cte.dir
        AND table_1.datetime BETWEEN cte.datetime - INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
                                      AND cte.datetime + INTERVAL '30 MINUTE'
ORDER BY id;

create DB queries -
CREATE TABLE table_1 
(
    id character varying NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(datetime, id),
    datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    col_1 int,
    col_2 int,
    dist int,
    dir character varying(5)
);
INSERT INTO 
table_1(id, datetime, col_1, col_2, dist, dir)
VALUES
  ('103', '2023-10-06 20:12:19', 135, 130, 57, 'EAST'),
  ('213', '2023-10-06 20:32:34', 135, 130, 54, 'NORTH'),
  ('103', '2023-10-06 20:00:19', 135, 130, 70, 'EAST'),
  ('103', '2023-10-06 20:42:34', 135, 130, 54, 'NORTH'),
  ('213', '2023-10-06 20:12:19', 135, 130, 57, 'NORTH'),
  ('222', '2023-10-06 18:42:34', 135, 130, 45, 'EAST'),
  ('222', '2023-10-06 20:42:34', 135, 130, 54, 'EAST');

dbfiddle

For PostgreSql 10  and earlier, you may use self join instead window function with time interval.
For partition
   PARTITION BY id, dir 
    ORDER BY datetime
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30 minute' PRECEDING
              AND INTERVAL '30 minute' FOLLOWING

use JOIN condition
on t2.id=t1.id and t2.dir=t1.dir
   and t2.datetime between t1.datetime - interval '30 min'
         and t1.datetime + interval '30 min'

See example
with jt as(
select t1.id,t1.datetime,t1.col_1,t1.col_2,t1.dist,t1.dir
  ,t2.id id2,t2.datetime datetime2,t2.col_1 col1_2,t2.col_2 col2_2,t2.dist dist2,t1.dir dir2
  ,max(t2.dist)over(partition by t1.id,t1.datetime,t1.dir) maxdist
  ,row_number()over(partition by t1.id,t1.datetime,t1.dir order by t2.dist)rnW
from table_1 t1
left join table_1 t2 on t2.id=t1.id and t2.dir=t1.dir
   and t2.datetime between t1.datetime - interval '30 min'
         and t1.datetime + interval '30 min'
)
select id, datetime, col_1, col_2, dist, dir
from jt
where dist=maxdist and rnW=1

Fiddle
Before filter we have



id
datetime
col_1
col_2
dist
dir
datetime2
dist2
maxdist
rnw




>103
2023-10-06 20:00:19
135
13
70
EAST
2023-10-06 20:12:19
57
70
1


103
2023-10-06 20:00:19
135
13
70
EAST
2023-10-06 20:00:19
70
70
2


103
2023-10-06 20:12:19
135
13
57
EAST
2023-10-06 20:12:19
57
70
1


103
2023-10-06 20:12:19
135
13
57
EAST
2023-10-06 20:00:19
70
70
2


>103
2023-10-06 20:42:34
135
13
54
NORTH
2023-10-06 20:42:34
54
54
1


>213
2023-10-06 20:12:19
135
13
57
NORTH
2023-10-06 20:32:34
54
57
1


213
2023-10-06 20:12:19
135
13
57
NORTH
2023-10-06 20:12:19
57
57
2


213
2023-10-06 20:32:34
135
13
54
NORTH
2023-10-06 20:32:34
54
57
1


213
2023-10-06 20:32:34
135
13
54
NORTH
2023-10-06 20:12:19
57
57
2


>222
2023-10-06 18:42:34
135
13
45
EAST
2023-10-06 18:42:34
45
45
1


>222
2023-10-06 20:42:34
135
13
54
EAST
2023-10-06 20:42:34
54
54
1




thank you for the answer @@ValNik. It's working as expected.

The following query returns the described result set:
WITH
  cte AS (
    SELECT id, datetime, col_1, col_2, dist, dir,
           MAX(dist) OVER (PARTITION BY id, dir ORDER BY datetime
                           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30 minute' PRECEDING
                                     AND INTERVAL '30 minute' FOLLOWING) AS max_dist
      FROM table_1)
SELECT id, datetime, col_1, col_2, dist, dir
  FROM cte
  WHERE dist = max_dist;

The query partitions the data by id and dir and determines the maximum dist within a +/- 30 minute range of each data point and then filters for only those rows where dist is equal to the corresponding maximum.

Thanks for the answer @JohnH, it's working fine in version 16. How can we convert and run the RANGE BETWEEN section in 9.0x postgres version because it's working in higher version?
